# How to find the minimum fields needed to identify a unique row in a set of data

Tags: database

Say I have a bunch of data on some people.  This could include Name, DOB, Address, Email, etc...  Assume there are no unique identifiers (like an id column) on this data, but also assume that there are no repeating rows.  I need to figure out the minimum set of fields I can use to query that data and return a unique row.

An example of a solution would be: "I can make a query that specifies a first name, dob, email, and zip, and that would return exactly one or zero rows."

Did I ask that in a way that makes sense?  I am looking for a technique, algorithm, or software package that would solve this problem for a given set of data.  Anything that could provide an answer would work.  Thanks!

EXAMPLE DATA (the real stuff is much more complex):

```
FNAME        LNAME         DOB          ZIP       email

John         Smith         1/1/12       77777     dude@fake.com
Sean         Smith         1/2/08       77777     dude@fake.com
Sean         William       4/2/07       77789     stuff@fake.com
Richard      Ross          1/1/12       78989     foo@fake.com
```

The solution for this set of data would be (FNAME, LNAME) or (EMAIL, DOB) or (EMIAL, FNAME).

Comment: so the MINIMAL set of columns should or should not include your first solution (with 3 columns)?

Comment: @Randy:  Sorry, edited that out.  It should always be the minimal number of columns.

Comment: What happens when you have two John Smiths with the same DOB or same ZIP or email (like noemail@noemail)? I've inherited a system where something like that can happen and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to sanitise the data, considering that all fields are optional (including ID number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you will need an iterative approach.

perhaps you can begin with each column, and attempt to create a unique index.

if you have success, then done.

if you are unable to create unique index then add another column and try again.

do this for all columns until you can successfully make the index.

Comment: if this is all done in order of your example the result should be unique index on : FNAME, LNAME